# jQueryUI and jQuery Plugin Conflict

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, plugins, conflict

I am using a jQuery plugin that goes in conflict with something in the **jQueryUI Effects Core**, much probably something to do with **ease animation**.

I can't post the code because the plugin is not open source, so my question is: is there any way I can catch this error and fix it?

In the jQueryUI Effects Core, both plugin **work properly** with no conflicts if I remove the following code

```
$.effects = {
    effect: {}
};
```

I don't even know what's that for, so I would like to understand.

Thanks in advance to anyone who will try to help me.

Comment: Without seeing your code it is a guessing game. Is your plugin setting a variable $.effects?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the development version of jQuery, if you are looking for a conflict within the library itself. I'm certain you are already using some sort of debug tool, such as firebug, or chromes javascript console. From there you just need to find the error and get a stack trace. Firefox's "Break on all errors" feature is useful in this case.

Also don't be afraid to add your own code to the development version of jquery. Mess it up and treat it as your own code, you can always download it again.

good luck!

Comment: I already tried that but i get NO errors.. this is the very strange thing! Thanks anyway for your anwer.. was encouraging ^^

Answer (score 1):

Many JavaScript libraries use `$` as a function or variable name, just as jQuery does. In jQuery's case, `$` is just an alias for `jQuery`, so all functionality is available without using $. If we need to use another JavaScript library alongside jQuery, we can return control of $ back to the other library with a call to `$.noConflict()`:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
</script>
```

This technique is especially effective in conjunction with the .ready() method's ability to alias the jQuery object, as within callback passed to .ready() we can use $ if we wish without fear of conflicts later:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="other_lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $.noConflict();
  jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
    // Code that uses jQuery's $ can follow here.
    $("div").hide();
  });
  // Code that uses other library's $ can follow here.
  $("content").style.display = 'none';
</script>
```

Source: [**jQuery.noConflict**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/)

Comment: I already read this but still didn't get how to use this. Can you make me an example, please?